# how to show bucket in bottomNavigationBar?

Tags: flutter, dart

I made a custom bottomNavitationBar and named it BottomBar. and I used it home_page and shop_page as bottomNavigationBar in Scaffold well. but shop_page shows that well but home_page doesn't show that totally. It's there's no bucket in bottomNavigationBar in home_page.. I don't know why they appear like this. I attached the screens.

[image]

[image]

--home_page-- (problem that not showing bucket in bottomNavigationBar here.. please review these codes.)

```
return Scaffold(
    bottomNavigationBar: BottomBar(),
        backgroundColor: Color(0xFF001947),
      body: CustomScrollView(
          slivers: [
          SliverFillRemaining(
          hasScrollBody: false,
          child:
          Column(
          children: [
            Container(
              width: double.infinity,
              height: 140,
              child: Center(
                child: Text("32.06 AVAX", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 30),

                )
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              width: double.infinity,
              height: 50,
                child: Center(
                    child: Text("Weekly Activation", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold))
                ),
            ),
            Container(
              width: double.infinity,
                child: Divider(color: Colors.grey, thickness: 0.3)
            ),
            Container(
                child: LineChartSample2()
            ),

            Flexible(

              fit: FlexFit.loose,
              child: Container(
                width: double.infinity,
                color: Colors.white,
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Container(
                        width: double.infinity,
                        height: 30,
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        children: [
                          Text("My Identification",style:
                            TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 20)),
                          ElevatedButton(onPressed: null,
                            style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)
                                ),
                            ),child: Icon(
                                  Icons.arrow_right
                              ),
                          )
                        ]
                      )
                    ),
                  Container(

                  child: SingleChildScrollView(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 100),
                    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                    child: cardWidget()
                  ),
                ),
                ]
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
          
        )

        ),
      ]
    )
)
```

--- Button Custom Widget Page ----

```
class BottomBar extends StatefulWidget {
  const BottomBar({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<BottomBar> createState() => _BottomBarState();
}

class _BottomBarState extends State<BottomBar> {

  int currentTab = 0;
  final List<Widget> screens = [
    HomePage(),
    ShopPage(),
    PeoplePage(),
    WalletPage()
  ];
  
  final PageStorageBucket bucket = PageStorageBucket();
  Widget currentScreen = HomePage();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BottomAppBar(
        shape: CircularNotchedRectangle(),
        notchMargin: 10,
        child: Container(
          height: 60,
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: <Widget>[
              Row(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  MaterialButton(
                    minWidth: 40,
                    onPressed: (){
                      setState(() {
                        currentScreen = HomePage();
                        currentTab = 0;
                      });
                    },
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        Icon(
                          Icons.home,
                          color: currentTab == 0? Colors.blue : Colors.grey,
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  MaterialButton(
                    minWidth: 40,
                    onPressed: (){
                      setState(() {
                        currentScreen = ShopPage();
                        currentTab = 1;
                      });
                    },
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        Icon(
                          Icons.shop,
                          color: currentTab == 1? Colors.blue : Colors.grey,
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              //Right Tab Bar Icons
              Row(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  MaterialButton(
                    minWidth: 40,
                    onPressed: (){
                      setState(() {
                        currentScreen = WalletPage();
                        currentTab = 2;
                      });
                    },
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        Icon(
                          Icons.wallet,
                          color: currentTab == 2? Colors.blue : Colors.grey,
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  MaterialButton(
                    minWidth: 40,
                    onPressed: (){
                      setState(() {
                        currentScreen = PeoplePage();
                        currentTab = 3;
                      });
                    },
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        Icon(
                          Icons.people,
                          color: currentTab == 3? Colors.blue : Colors.grey,
                        ),

                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could simple use this flutter package for easy implementation of curved navigation bar [curved_navigation_bar](https://pub.dev/packages/curved_navigation_bar)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3BCtD.gif)

Add dependency :

```
dependencies:
   curved_navigation_bar: ^1.0.3 #latest version
```

**code**

```
  int _page = 0;
  GlobalKey<CurvedNavigationBarState> _bottomNavigationKey = GlobalKey();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        bottomNavigationBar: CurvedNavigationBar(
          key: _bottomNavigationKey,
          items: <Widget>[
            Icon(Icons.add, size: 30),
            Icon(Icons.list, size: 30),
            Icon(Icons.compare_arrows, size: 30),
          ],
          onTap: (index) {
            setState(() {
              _page = index;
            });
          },
        ),
        body: Container(
          color: Colors.blueAccent,
          child: Center(
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(_page.toString(), textScaleFactor: 10.0),
                ElevatedButton(
                  child: Text('Go To Page of index 1'),
                  onPressed: () {
                    //Page change using state does the same as clicking index 1 navigation button
                    final CurvedNavigationBarState? navBarState =
                        _bottomNavigationKey.currentState;
                    navBarState?.setPage(1);
                  },
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }
```